# Proxying with SSL

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have a Linux host running Apache and a Windows host running IIS.  I have a domain that points to the Linux host and need to relay (proxy) requests for it to IIS; I thus have the following virtual host definition in Apache (which works just fine):

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:80>
    ServerName www.acme.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acme.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://win.acme.com/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

now I want to add SSL support; the definition becomes:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.2:443>
    ServerName www.acme.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acme.com
    GnuTLSEnable On
    GnuTLSPriorities NORMAL:%COMPAT
    GnuTLSCertificateFile /var/www/ssl/www.acme.com.crt
    GnuTLSKeyFile /var/www/ssl/www.acme.com.key

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://win.acme.com/$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have valid and trusted certificates on both web servers and if I visit `https://win.acme.com` all is well, however, when I visit `https://www.acme.com` I get a 500 Internal Server Error message.  A peek at the error logs shows:

> [Wed Jul 20 08:35:34 2011] [error] [client 76.168.166.70] SSL Proxy
>   requested for www.wileybits.com:80 but not enabled [Hint:
>   SSLProxyEngine] [Wed Jul 20 08:35:34 2011] [error] proxy: HTTPS:
>   failed to enable ssl support for 74.166.186.70:443 (win.acme.com)

do notice that the proxy request seems to be for the wrong domain (wileybits)... the domain it shows is also hosted by my Apache server but I don't get why it shows up in the logs of acme.com (a reverse DNS lookup perhaps?)

in any case, what am I missing?

thanks in advance - ekkis

p.s. host names and addresses have been altered to protect the innocent :)

*** update ***

with:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://win.acme.com/$1 [R,L]
```

it seems to work fine, but of course, the Windows' hostname becomes visible, which is not acceptable in my scenario

I also tried (instead of mod_rewrite):

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / https://win.acme.com/
```

but same error

Comment: why did I get a minus point for this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

figured it out... apparently I can do this:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
ProxyPass / https://win.acme.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://win.acme.com/
CacheDisable *
```

and it works just fine!

[the solution came from [mikeg's posting](https://web.archive.org/web/20111202042335/http://3cx.org/item/46) on 3cx.org]

Comment: For those who find this later: my issue was not including `SSLProxyEngine on`. Note that it cannot be in an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You also need to `sudo a2enmod headers proxy ssl cache`
and add SSLEngine on (else i got an error `[error] Oops, no RSA or DSA server certificate found for 'www.somedomain.com:0'?!`) and SSLCertificateFile/SSLCertificateKeyFile with same key & certificate

Comment: For others who look at this and may be confused: `Front-End-Https` is a [proprietary flag for Microsoft applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) and doesn't need to be set when proxying to other services.

Comment: I believe it is now CacheDisable /

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the cause of this error, but you might want you try using Squid or Varnish to accomplish this. Previously, I've used Squid to proxy a secure Windows IIS instance without issue.